# Self-Register with Flow , Welcome email with URL link direct back to Self-Register Page again

Tags: experience-cloud, flow-builder, self-registration

I need to implement self-registration flow logic in our community that, when user completes the register form, expands self-registration functionality past the creation of account, contact, and user records. I used the Self-Register standard page in Experience Builder to configure. I expected the user will get a Welcome Email with community URL link to setup their password and complete the process.

I got a Welcome Email but after clicking the Community link, it directed me to the Self-register page instead of Change Password Page. Does any one know why and please help !

Comment: I found the reason. I assigned the flow to a specific profile in the Login Flows setting. That's why after users complete the login flow, they're logged in and  it redirects them back to the self-register page

Comment: Could you answer your question with a proper answer instead of a comment? (Yes, it's possible!) That will help people finding your question in the future.